# Pass param to app when installed from Google Play

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-install-apk

I need to support the following scenario:

User receives the e-mail with link to my app.

If user already has the app installed the link should open the app passing some data in the intent to the launcher activity.

If the app is not installed yet the e-mail link should act as campaign referrer: direct user to Google Play to install the app with referrer url that is passed to my app after installation in referrer broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 12):

You need to intercept the `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` Intent, which is broadcast by Google Play after the app is opened for the first time after installation, and catch the data in that Intent. The parameters in the URI used to launch Google Play will be passed along in the `referrer` String extra. (Though you are limited to a list of allowed params, see the official docs for that table.)

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns

Edit: Google has announced in an email sent to developers that as of March 1, 2020, they will no longer be supporting this. Developers need to use the new API  https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library.html.